# python input issues with mac

Tags: python, macos

I am new to python and been playing around but I am getting a error on the mac

below is the code I have in the input.py file

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello', person)
```

If I run the code this is my output and error

```
Johnathans-iMac:scripts johnathansmith$ python input.py 
Enter your name: John
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input.py", line 1, in <module>
    person = input('Enter your name: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

Please keep in mind that I am new.. what can it be?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question; that question deals specifically with unexpected evaluation of user input when using `input`; @John is using `raw_input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using Python 2.7. The reason is that with this version of Python, the `input` function asks for a string from the user, then *tries to evaluate that string*. Since `John` is not defined in your code, Python complains.

Try to either run `python3`, or change to using `raw_input` instead of `input`.

With Python 3 (output from interactive session):

```
> person = input('Enter name:')
Enter name:John

> print('Hey', person)
Hey John
```

With Python 2:

```
> person = raw_input('Enter name:')
Enter name:John
> print 'Hey', person
Hey John
```

Comment: @Afflicted From your link: `input([prompt]): Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))`, which is what I tried to explain in the answer. Never said input is for python 3 only. And `raw_input` is _not_ considered worse. In fact, the Python 3 version of `input` is what Python 2 calls `raw_input`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
person = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
print 'Hello', person
```

In Python2, you need to use `raw_input` to get user input from the command line. In Python2, `print` is a statement. Putting the parentheses around the arguments causes a `tuple` to be created and passed to the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are running **Python 3** code on a **Python 2** interpreter. Either upgrade your python with [homebrew](http://brew.sh) `brew install python3` or use `raw_input` for python 2

In Python 2, raw_input() returns a string, and input() tries to run the input as a Python expression.

Comment: Thanks I got it working better with the raw_input but the output is still not working 'Enter your name: john
('Hi, ', 'john')
Johnathans-iMac:scripts johnathansmith$'

Comment: How is it not working? Try putting print('Hello' + ' ' + person) otherwise, you won't get a space between hello and person. update your question with the new output issue, not an additional comment.

Comment: for the output I am getting "('Hi, ', ' john')

Comment: Like I said update your original question with your current output so it's easier to read in the proper format!!

Answer (score -3):

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')
print('Hello' + ' ' + person)

Enter your name: Aaron
Hello Aaron
```

Using the same os as the op and this is what I've done, and received as output.

```
input() # Is NOT a python 3 dependant function as clearly stated in the docs.
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

"
input([prompt])
Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.

Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.
"

It's neither proper nor improper to use input, in fact, it's typically better the suggestion to use raw_input() comes from old issues that no longer exist, and in this specific situation would not affect the Op.

Furthermore, any syntax errors that exist will occur on the same level while using raw_input there is no valid argument in this situation to use raw_input() over input() lol

Downvoting a correct answer because you're angry that you're wrong is a violation of the rules, it's sad how cancerous and incorrect this site has become in the last few months.

Comment: You are getting downvoted because this will not solve the OPs problem. This will throw a `NameError` in Python 2, which the OP is clearly using.

Comment: In Python 2, when using `input()` to read strings, you need to input it with quotes, different from `raw_input()` and Python 3's `input()` that you can just type as you wish

Comment: Also, using Python 2's `input()` is considered bad for code injection reasons as well, so your "old issues that no longer exist" statement is wrong

Comment: It really doesn’t but that’s okay Felipe.